# How does /proc interact with PID namespaces?

Tags: linux, proc, namespace

I do not understand how namespaces interact with `/proc`. I assumed that `/proc` returns values based on the process that queries them.

For example, let's determine the PID of the current process inside the global PID namespace:

```
$ bwrap --bind / / readlink /proc/self
6182
```

This makes sense to me. However, when I isolate `readlink` in its own PID namespace:

```
$ bwrap --bind / / --unshare-pid readlink /proc/self
6177
```

I get the same result! To get the PID inside the namespace, I need to add `--proc /proc`:

```
$ bwrap --bind / / --unshare-pid --proc /proc readlink /proc/self
2
```

But shouldn't `/proc` always take the context of the reading process into account? Why is the extra `procfs` required and how is it related to the `readlink` process?

If I do not create a new PID namespace, the extra `procfs` makes no difference:

```
$ bwrap --bind / / --proc /proc readlink /proc/self
6179
```

Comment: I guess it's using the namespace of the process that mounted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the gotchas of namespaces. With

```
bwrap --bind / / --unshare-pid readlink /proc/self
```

you’ve created a new PID namespace, and a new mount namespace (because `bwrap` does that by default), but you’re explicitly bind-mounting the external `/` into that mount namespace. The result is that, inside the new mount namespace, `/proc` is the same as outside — try

```
bwrap --bind / / --unshare-pid ps -ef
```

The key feature here is described [in `man pid_namespaces`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html):

> A `/proc` filesystem shows (in the `/proc/[pid]` directories) only
> processes visible in the PID namespace of the process **that
> performed the mount**, even if the `/proc` filesystem is viewed from
> processes in other namespaces.

(emphasis mine). You can see [`/proc` memorising the appropriate PID namespace here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/fs/proc/root.c#L247).

So `readlink` sees `/proc` through the eyes of the PID namespace that performed the mount, not through its own PID namespace.

Adding `--proc=/proc` mounts `/proc` anew, inside the forked `bwrap` in the new PID namespace, so its contents reflect the new PID namespace.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of mounts being related to the process that mounted them. Thanks!I experimented a bit with this and it shows some dangers if the process inside has the permissions to unmount `/proc` and then access the original `/proc`. With `bubblewrap` this was not possible, but with `unshare` it was.